# Handle nested Interval in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Some issue here;

I've got an HTTP GET call, that runs in an interval every 3 seconds.
The call's response data is an array of objects, and I want to log them to the console.

How can I avoid collision between intervals?

An example:

```
    setInterval(function(){
        $http.get('/some/api').then(function(dataArray){
            dataArray.forEach(function(element){
                  setInterval(function(){
                      console.log(element);
                  },1000)
            });
        })
    },5000)
```

Assume that the arrays from the api are: [1,2,3] at the first time, and [4,5,6] at the second interval, I need to see:
1
2
3
4
5
6

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want a 1 second pause between outputting each item return? Why not just output it as you receive it? And the code you have runs every 5 seconds not every 3 seconds.

Comment: You'd need to stop the inner interval once you're through the array.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute `setTimout()` for `setInterval()`; multiply the `index` of `.forEach()` callback function by `duration` `1000`

```js
var dataArray = [1, 2, 3];
dataArray.forEach(function(element, index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(element);
  }, 1000 * index)
});
```

You can alternatively call `clearInterval()` at each successful response, use `Promise.all()`, `Promise()` constructor, substitute `.map()` for `.forEach()`, call `setInterval` at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()` when all `setTimeout()` calls have completed within `Promise()` constructor

```
function delay() {
  return $http.get('/some/api').then(function(dataArray) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    return Promise.all(dataArray.map(function(element, index) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(element);
            resolve();
          }, 1000);
        });
      }))
      .then(function() {
        interval = setInterval(delay, 5000)
      });
  })
}

interval = setInterval(delay, 5000);
```

```js
function get() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(Array.from(Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).keys()))
  })
}

function delay() {
  return get().then(function(dataArray) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("current `dataArray.length`:", dataArray.length);
    return Promise.all(dataArray.map(function(element, index) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(element);
            resolve()
          }, 1000 * index)
        })
      }))
      .then(function() {
        interval = setInterval(delay, 5000)
      });
  })
}

interval = setInterval(delay, 5000)
```

Comment: `$http.get('/some/api')` called every 5000ms. When 1000 * index > 5000, output will interleave.

Comment: @gzc _"When 1000 * index > 5000, output will interleave"_ Original Question describes expected response of array having three elements each _"Assume that the arrays from the api are: [1,2,3] at the first time, and [4,5,6] at the second interval"_. `1000 * index > 5000` should not occur given description at OP. If there are more than three elements returned as response `setInteval` can be cleared at each response, then called again when `.forEach()`, `setTimeout` calls complete.

Comment: the array length can be changed.. for example [1,2] and next time [4,7,6,8,3,2] and then [1] ...

Answer (score 2):

I would want to get away from this nested intervals, other approach what I can think of is to have a `array` that adds on the data into it from each `$http.get('/some/api')` call and I will have another function outside of this interval which purely works on the `array` variable. To be clear let see this sample.

```
var valuesToLog =[];  // holds the elements 

setInterval(function(){
  $http.get('/some/api').then(function(dataArray){
      valuesToLog.push(dataArray);  //keep adding into the array for logging
  })
},5000)

//new player which runs every second.
setInterval(funcion(){
   if(valuesToLog.length){
     console.log(valuesToLog[0]); //log first item
     valuesToLog.splice(0,1) // and remove the logged item. ie: first item
   }
},1000);
```

So every second I log the first item in the array and remove it.. Also since the interval is never killed it checks the array every second and if items are present it will log..

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks my friend, its helped my to understand the issue better !